# How to copy values for the char **a - C

Tags: c, arrays, copy, c-strings

In this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void givetome(char** skey);
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char *skey[5];
    givetome(&skey[5]);
    printf("%s\n",*skey);
    return 0;
}
void givetome(char **skey){
    char f[5]={'g','h','f','d','s'};
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        *skey[i]=f[i];
    }
}
```

I'm not able to copy the values from the vector "f" to the vector "skey". Someone to help?

Comment: don't add stars at random. You want to store `char`s in the array `skey`? Why is it an array of `char*` then? --> `char skey[5]`. You want `skey` to be a C-string containing 5 characters? Then it has to have room for 6 so there is space for the terminating `'\0'` after the characters. Why do you want to pass a pointer to a pointer to char to `givetome()`? a `char` array will decay to a `char*` which is enoug to write to it. `void givetome(char** skey);` --> `void givetome(char *skey);`, `void givetome(char **skey){` --> `void givetome(char *skey) {`. As I said before, you have to terminate a

Comment: C-string with `'\0'`. Last line of `givetome()`: `skey[5] = '\0';`. `printf("%s\n",*skey);` --> `puts(skey);`

Comment: @Johnathan Wrong language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `givetome(&skey[5])`, you start assigning characters at the end of `skey` and thereby exceed array bounds then. With `givetome(&skey[0])` or simply `givetome(skey)` it should work.

BTW: as you print the result as a string, you'll need to terminate the string with `'\0'`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void givetome(char* skey);
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char skey[6];
    givetome(skey);
    skey[5] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n",skey);
    return 0;
}
void givetome(char *skey){
    char f[5]={'g','h','f','d','s'};
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        skey[i]=f[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: I try with "givetome(&skey[0])" and  "givetome(skey)" but don't work to

Comment: added complete program.

Comment: where u say skey[5]='\0'  is 6. that it tanks

Comment: @user48571 the '\0' is called a null terminator. printf and all string functions require all char *'s passed to them to end in '\0'.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of problems here.

You defined `skey` as an array of pointers.  What you want is an array of characters:

```
char skey[5];
```

Then when you call the function:

```
givetome(&skey[5]);
```

You pass the address of the array element with index 5.  The largest index in an array of size 5 is 4, so you're passing a pointer to one past the end of the array.  You want to pass the array by name, which passes in the address of the first element.

```
givetome(skey);
```

Then, since we've redefined `skey`, we need to change `givetome` to accept a `char *`.  Then when assigning, assign to `skey[i]`, not `*skey[i]`.

You'll also have a problem printing because `%s` expects a string, which is defined as a null-terminated array of characters.  The array doesn't contain a null byte, so printing will read past the end of the array.  So add a null byte to the end of `f` and save room for it in `skey`.

With all the changes, the code should look like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void givetome(char *skey);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char skey[6];
    givetome(skey);
    printf("%s\n", skey);
    return 0;
}

void givetome(char *skey){
    char f[6]={'g','h','f','d','s', '\0'};
    for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        skey[i]=f[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: I need the changes to be saved in the main function vector. So I need "char ** skey".

Comment: @user48571 No you don't.  When you pass `skey` to the function, you're actually passing a pointer to the first element.  Since this: `skey[i]` is the same as: `*(skey + i)`, you're dereferencing that pointer and writing to the dereferenced location, meaning that updates to the array in `givetome` are visible in `main`.

Comment: user48571 if your function takes a non const pointer the results will be visible in main. char ** is a jagged array. char * is an array. a vector can resize its self, i.e. std::vector. use dbush's example.

Comment: @dbush your forward decleration is wrong, should be char *.

Comment: @Johnathan Thanks.  Fixed.